# Github - main branch is 10 commits ahead itself

Tags: github

When working on my assignment created through github classroom, I am on the main branch, but it still says "This branch is 10 commits ahead of main". Why would this happen as the main branch is supposed to be equal to itself?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn2EJ.png)

I checked all branches, and there is only one branch named main. Also the local main branch says "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'", so it shouldn't be the cause.

Comment: Would you post a url to your repository, if possible?

Comment: 1) It could just be GitHub is broken. That happens. It will probably resolve itself. 2) What is the name of the second branch?

Comment: That or the main the link is referring to might be in the repo you forked, I wouldn't know, GitHub is in some ways a subset, someways a superset of Git, .

Comment: @Schwern I can't make the repo public as that's probably somehow controlled by github classroom. The second branch is called feedback, which is automatically added by github classroom.

Comment: @jthill I have been using github classroom a lot, and in previous assignments the main always refers the main branch of my repo. So I'm just confused how branch can be different to itself..

Comment: Seems like a GitHub bug, there's not enough info to say more. Try reporting it to GitHub support.

Comment: Could you show log graph of git tree with
git log --graph

Before show log, use:
git fetch origin
It can give more information about your problem.

Comment: @AnthonyNguyen It seems all fine. All commits are there

Comment: I think it might be caused by some permission errors (not sure) - I tried deleting the whole repo and reaccepted the assignment, but the error still persists, and now main is 5 commits ahead itself (because github classroom made some updates to the workflow upon the acceptance of the assignent). So I think the error has nothing to do with my own commits made later. But since I dropped the class a few weeks ago before I first accepted the assignment, maybe something behind the scene is messed up by some permission errors